# DJ Native Swing Browser for Java

Tags: java, macos, swing, djnativeswing

I have use a browser that is [DJ enabled Browser](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/) of Swing. I have jars for the Windows and Linux that is swt.jars and but which jar will I need to run same program for the MAC OS using Java?

Comment: Why not `Desktop#browse()`?

Comment: @trashgod m asking about jar dude.

Comment: If you don't find a better solution, `Desktop#browse()` has been in the JRE since version 6.

Comment: @trashgod i know that but i need to open it into swing browser only. my requirement is just like that. and ya so m asking for required jar files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use  swt-mac.jar
you can download latest version
http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.2.2-201302041200/index.php#SWT

Comment: R u sure that it will run on this?

Comment: and how do i run that. and ya shell i have to put that swt.jar and swt-debug.jar into the lib folder in that or classpath?

Answer (score 0):

After waiting long finally i found jar files for that.

here

http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/S-4.4M5-201401231600/

in that

Mac OSX (Mac/Cocoa/x86_64)
that is for 64 bit mac systems. I run in mac With that swt.jar